# Remove Sprite Shape Controller Icons from 2D sprite shapes

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites

How do I get rid of those "purple icons in my scene"? They are so annoying ... they literally covers the entire 2d shape! [GIF showcasing it](https://gyazo.com/41a4ef0fed9fbf40a9f7beab5cb55185)

[image: prite]

Comment: Do you see a toggle for them in the Gizmos dropdown at the top of the Scene panel?

Comment: @DMGregory That worked, thanks! I didn't know about the Gizmo thingy.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please write up your solution as an answer below, ideally with a screenshot. This can help other devs who run into the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ### **The icons can be turned on/off from under the Gizmo tap.**

[image]